# Pip installs to wrong directory

Tags: python, pip

I'm on OS X and my Pip installs to

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

I would like my pip to install to:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

How could I achieve this? I haven't found a way yet

Comment: Windows or mac?

Comment: OS X, updating the answer now

Comment: use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pip has an option for target directory --target, when installing package use

```
pip install --target=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages package_name
```

to install to your `target` directory.

> if target option not available, check `pip` version & for possible
>   upgrade or as mentioned in comments the error may be related to OSX/Homebrew install, check [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Homebrew-and-Python.md) for details.

Comment: `$ pip install --target=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages pydub` returns as `DistutilsOptionError: must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both`

Comment: Thanks, I will upvote this when I have back under my limit (2h)